# Vegas window is blank

Tags: scala, vegas-viz

The following Vegas window is blank when I plot it:

```
package com.plot

import vegas.Bar
import vegas.DSL.OptArg.anyToOpt
import vegas.DefaultValueTransformer
import vegas.Nom
import vegas.Quant
import vegas.Vegas
import vegas.render.WindowRenderer.toWindow

object Plot {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val plot = Vegas("Country Pop").
      withData(
        Seq(
          Map("country" -> "USA", "population" -> 314),
          Map("country" -> "UK", "population" -> 64),
          Map("country" -> "DK", "population" -> 80))).
        encodeX("country", Nom).
        encodeY("population", Quant).
        mark(Bar)
    plot.show
  }
}
```

Here is the resulting blank window:

[image]

Comment: While _Vegas_ may use _ScalaFX_, this problem is entirely related to the _Vegas_ API and has nothing to do with _ScalaFX_.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas) it appears that _Vegas_ is designed to be run from notebook applications, such as [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/). I'm guessing it's not possible to run it as an application (via a `main` function) because doing so will not initialize the underlying _JavaFX_ environment.